# Pandas Frame Iteration : Efficiency

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 separate datasets

Dataset 1: Database of Items that are loaded and When they were Loaded. It Looks something like this
[Loaded DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcNxZ.png)

Dataset 2 : Database of Items that are Unloaded and when they were Unloaded. It Loos Exactly Similar to the Above Data set

hse_time is of the format "2016-01-07 19:38:56" i.e. "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"

Now my exercise is to tag Each Loaded Item with the corresponding Unloaded Time, Number of Times Loaded and Number of times Unloaded, Current Status[Loaded or Unloaded]

The Dataset has following rules:

1. An Item can be Loaded and Unloaded multiple Times.
2. Since this is for a Particular Time-Frame we can have an Item Unloaded beforfe it is loaded in the dataset[For eg: I am analysing JFM'16 data its possible that it was loaded before in Dec'15 but Unloaded in Jan'16)
3. No of times Loaded = Number of Times Unloaded
4. No of times Loaded = Number of times Unloaded + 1

Now I have written an Algorithm to satisfy all the Conditions and Tag everything I need but the Problem is I have a Data set of 400K and it takes forever for my algorithm to run since I've to Iterate Over each Row in the Loaded Frame.

AnyOther Way to do this so that I can reduce my Run time?

Here is my Code:

```
Loaded_Frame     = Loaded_Frame.sort_values(by=["BranchID","hse_time"],ascending=True)
Unloaded_Frame   = Unloaded_Frame.sort_values(by["BranchID","hse_time"],ascending=True)
Grouped          = Loaded_Frame.groupby(["BranchID","Item Name"]).agg({"weight":"count"}).reset_index()
Grouped.rename(columns={"weight":"LoadedCount"},inplace=True)
temp_frame       = Unloaded_Frame.groupby(["BranchID","Item Name"]).agg({"weight":"count"}).reset_index()
temp_frame.rename(columns={"weight":"UnLoadedCount"},inplace=True)
Grouped          = Grouped.merge(temp_frame,on=["BranchID","Item Name"],how="outer")
Grouped["UnLoadedCount"] = Grouped["UnLoadedCount"].fillna(0)
Grouped["LoadedCount"]   = Grouped["LoadedCount"].fillna(0)
```

The Main Logic

```
import numpy as np
Final_Frame=Loaded_Frame.copy()
Final_Frame["Multiple Loads"]=np.nan
Final_Frame["Number of times Loaded"]=np.nan
Final_Frame["Number of times UnLoaded"]=np.nan
Final_Frame["UnLoaded Date"]=np.nan
Final_Frame["Load Status"]=np.nan

for i in Grouped.index:
   x=UnLoaded_Frame[(UnLoaded_Frame["BranchID"]==Grouped.loc[i,"BranchID"])\
                 & (UnLoaded_Frame["Item Name"]==Grouped.loc[i,"Item Name"])].reset_index()
y=Loaded_Frame[(Loaded_Frame["BranchID"]==Grouped.loc[i,"BranchID"]) \
               & (Loaded_Frame["Item Name"]==Grouped.loc[i,"Item Name"])].reset_index()
Loaded_Count=y["BranchID"].count()
Unloaded-Count=x["BranchID"].count()

if Loaded_Count==Unloaded: #Condition where both are equal
    Multiple_Load=False
    if Loaded_Count>1:
        Multiple_Load=True
    else:
        Multiple_Load=False
    for j in y.index:
    Final_Frame.loc[((Final_Frame["BranchID"]==y.loc[j,"BranchID"]) \
                     & (Final_Frame["Item Name"]==y.loc[j,"Item Name"]) \
                     & (Final_Frame["hse_time"]==y.loc[j,"hse_time"]))\
                    ,["Multiple Loads","Number of times Loaded","Number of times UnLoaded","UnLoaded Date","Load Status"]]\
    =[Multiple_Load,Loaded_Count,UnLoaded_Count,x.loc[j,"hse_time"],"Unloaded"]
```

The Problem is While i run this code, It takes a lot of time Iterating Over 400K records.

Comment: @Merlin I have added the code, Thanks!

Comment: @Merlin Sure! I have made the changes :)

Comment: Also Edit the code for indents so it readable

Comment: @Merlin Have made the changes

Comment: I thinking you need to look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html.

Comment: So I think that Merging is the Solultion, but the Problem is I need to have Conditional Merging and the Condition is Date and Time Dependent.

So till now I have been Iterating Over rows and achieving this, but I was wondering if there was any efficient way to do this

Comment: Merge first, Then use np.where for conditional if statements.

Comment: @Merlin Let me Try out this solution, Theoretically it should Work.

Nevertheless, Thank you for taking out your time and helping me

Comment: There is no reason to sort by values then do a groupby. Groupby will sort on its own.